# Custom validation attribute using data annotations and code first

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, annotations, entity-framework-4.1

I have written a custom validation method using customvalidation attribute in C# 4.0. I am using code for Entity Framework 4.1. However the custom validation attribute method is static. How can I validate some other logic in my class while referencing other non-static fields within the same class.

i.e.

```
public class Foo
{
   [CustomerValidation(typeOf(Foo), "ValidatePoints"]
   public string Points { get; set; }

   public string AdvancedPoints { get; set;}

   public static ValidationResult ValidatePoints(string _Name)
   {
       if (_Name != AdvancedPoints) //Note that AdvancedPoints here is non-static and                                         should not be here. but i want to know how i can achieve this. 
       {     
           return ValidationResult.Success;
       }
       else
           return new ValidationResult("Wrong entry");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at `IValidatableObject`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx

It allows you to add class or multi-property validations for a given class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a class with static method in it.and use that method for validating class like this:

```
 [CustomValidation(typeof(Validate_Foo), "Validate")]
 public class Foo
```

and

```
 public class Validate_Foo
{
    public static ValidationResult Validate(Foo obj, ValidationContext vc)
    {
         return ValidationResult.Success;
         //or return new ValidationResult("Error"); 
    }
}
```